# how to move two stickers in same layout android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have two stickers and I want both the stickers to move zoom rotate. when I add ontouchlistener to both only 1 sticker implements the operations.

this is the code where I am setting the listener

```
ImageView crown = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.crown);
    crown.setOnTouchListener(this);

    ImageView crown1 = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.crown1);
    crown1.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

this is xml file of my layout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/editpic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/thumb" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crown"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/crown1" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crown1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/crown2" >
        </ImageView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

let me know if anyone has this solution.

update:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onTouch !!");
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;



        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                        - start.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
                if (lastEvent != null) {
                    newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - d;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                            view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        return true;
    }

    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

Comment: Where is code for `onTouch()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add code in condition for different `viewId` in `onTouch()` method.

Try like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.crown:
        // put code for 1st crown touch
        break;
    case R.id.crown1:
        // put code for 2nd crown touch
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have given the imageview parameters as fillparent so only one image does the operaions.. but if given wrap content image does not move in the whole layout

Comment: I mean this solution did not work because I have given the imageview parameters as fillparent so only one image does the operaions.. but if given wrap content image does not move in the whole layout

Answer (score 0):

try this,

http://code.almeros.com/android-multitouch-gesture-detectors#.Uw8US9SSywd

i think this may solve your problem.

Comment: only single image detects the ontouch that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

yeah I know i'm damn late but thought to share it so it may help others in future..

If you want to do move,resize,scaling,rotation with more than 2 views in same layout you can go for [android multi-touch controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/) ,It simplifies the somewhat messy and inconsistent MotionEvent touch point API.

The controller also supports pinch-zoom, including tracking the transformation between screen coordinates and object coordinates.

The controller was recently updated to support pinch-rotate, allowing you to physically twist objects using two touch points on the screen.

The controller makes it very easy to work with a canvas of separate objects (e.g. a stack of photos), each of which can be separately dragged with a single touch point or scaled with a pinch operation.